# I Can't install Laravel 4's package

Tags: class, laravel, package

I just started learn Laravel 4, i have problem when install laravel's package, in this case it is: http://packalyst.com/packages/package/greggilbert/recaptcha

I do all steps, but it always display: Class 'Greggilbert\Recaptcha\RecaptchaServiceProvider' not found

I think problem is i don't know where to put recaptcha-master.zip, root folder? or in Vendor folder? i don't know :(

Please help, thank you so much :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to add `"greggilbert/recaptcha": "dev-master"` to the require section of your `composer.json` file found in the Laravel root.

Once thats done you then need to install composer globally or download a copy of composer.phar and move it to your Laravel root.

Once either of those methods have been completed, you then need to run either `composer update` if you installed composer globally or `php composer.phar update` in order to install the new packages.

After, and only after composer has updated with the new dependencies you should then add the service providers and other configurations to Laravel.

Heres a link to the composer site. http://getcomposer.org/

Comment: My bad, all things work pretty work now, Thank you so much :)